# LINQ query results and null values

Tags: vb.net, linq

I'm having trouble with null values in my LINQ query.

This is my query:

```
Dim partsquery = (From u In parts.AsEnumerable() _
                   Where u.Field(Of String)("PART_GRP").Equals(sPartType) 
                   Select PART_GRP = u.Field(Of String)("PART_GRP"), Serial_Num = u.Field(Of String)("PART_SN"),
                   Position = u.Field(Of Integer?)("PART_POS_NUM"))
```

In my code, after the query, in a For Loop I have:

```
If partsquery.Count >= i Then

    If Not IsDBNull(partsquery(i).Position) Then
        sPartsPosition = partsquery(i).Position.ToString
    End If
```

On the "IF NOT..." line I'm getting: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

I've tried

```
If Not partsquery(i).Position Is Nothing Then
```

and

```
If partsquery(i).Position.HasValue Then
```

and they all give me "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" or "Nullable object must have a value".

In my query, the Position field is nullable which I thought meant null values are allowed so I would expect "" to be assigned to the string variable. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `partsquery(i)` must be null.  Check `If Not partsquery(i) Is Nothing` or even `If partsquery(i) IsNot Nothing`.

Comment: Thanks @Slippery Pete, I'm checking partsquery(i) with a count statement. I added that to the code snippet above.

Comment: methinks should be `If partsquery.Count > i Then` instead of `partsquery.Count >= i Then`